# Editable registration date field in user profile

Tags: users, profiles

I'm using this code to display in the user profile backend a field that will show the registration date of the user.

When I change the date and hit save, the registration date wont change, it will keep showing the original date.

How can I make this work?

Thanks

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<h3><?php _e("Información AbIbBEV", "blank"); ?></h3>

<table class="form-table">
<tr>
<th><label for="user_registered"><?php _e("Fecha de ingreso Empleado"); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="user_registered" id="user_registered" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
<span class="description"><?php _e("Fecha de ingreso del empleado."); ?></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
update_user_meta ( $user_id, 'user_registered', $user->user_registered );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `user_registered` field is not in `wp_usermeta`, but `wp_user`. You should be using `wp_update_user`:

```php
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<h3><?php _e("Información AbIbBEV", "blank"); ?></h3>

<table class="form-table">
<tr>
<th><label for="user_registered"><?php _e("Fecha de ingreso Empleado"); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="user_registered" id="user_registered" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
<span class="description"><?php _e("Fecha de ingreso del empleado."); ?></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    wp_update_user(
        [
            'ID'              => $user_id,
            'user_registered' => $user->user_registered,
        ]
    );
}
```

You may need to adjust your other code to pull from the user's data and not their meta.